# How to add link to custom module configuration form in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, forms, navigation

I'm working on a custom module that has a couple configuration form for controlling it's settings. I want to add a link to this form to the admin configuration UI. The new link to my settings isn't appearing, but the form works fine if I navigate directly to it using the URL.

```
# stripedonation.links.menu.yml

stripedonation.admin:
  title: 'Stripe Donation'
  description: 'Manage settings for strip donations'
  parent: system.admin_config_system
  # menu_name: main
  route_name: stripedonation.settings
  weight: 1
```

NOTE: I cleared the cache after adding this.

```
# stripedonation.routing.yml

stripedonation.settings:
  path: '/admin/config/stripedonation'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\stripedonation\Form\SettingsForm'
    _title: 'Stipe Donation Settings'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site config'
```

I also tried adding the key shown below to my *.info.yml file and it didn't help

```
# stripedonation.info.yml

name: "Stripe Donation"
type: module
description: "Adds Stripe Donation form for ThinkShout vetting exercrise"
package: EmersonThis
core: 8.x
# configure: stripedonation.settings
```

In case it matters...

```
# stripedonation.settings.yml
stripe_pub_key: ''
stripe_secret_key: ''
```

I'm expecting my menu link to show up here (but obviously it is not):
[image]

I've studied the following documentation:

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/defining-and-using-your-own-configuration-in-drupal-8
- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/working-with-configuration-forms

I've also studied every "how-to" I could find:

- http://befused.com/drupal/menu-links-custom-module-d8
- https://www.thirdandgrove.com/creating-a-simple-configuration-form-Drupal-8
- http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/step-by-step-method-to-create-a-custom-form-in-drupal-8

Still no menu in the admin UI. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you clear the cache after adding the menu.yml?

Comment: @Kevin Good question. Yes, I did make sure to clear the cache

Comment: There are no typos in the filename correct? For the yaml files?

Comment: You might just be missing `menu_name: admin` in the link definition

Comment: @Kevin The filenames were correct, but as I was double-checking them I found the problem. (See below) Your line of questioning lead me to the solution so if you submit an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Well it turned out to be a stupid mistake!

All of my filenames and syntax were correct, but my *.links.menu.yml accidentally was saved into the src/ directory of my module instead of at the root of it. I moved it where it should be and cleared the cache and it works fine.

Comment: Yep, it happens in the beginning. Once you get your feet wet some more, look into using Drupal Console to generate this stuff.